# JavaScript onClick function

Tags: javascript

Нужно каким-то образом изменить значение переменной `num` в первой функции, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать ее, уже измененную, во второй функции.

Что делать - не представляю. Дайте наводку, пожалуйста. С примером будет вообще прекрасно.

```
var num = " "; 
function SaveValue(Value){ 
  if (Value.onclick){ 
    num = Value.value
  } 
  return num;
}

function ChangeValue(Element,num){
  if (Element.onclick) {
    Element.value = num;
    num = " ";
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Не понятно, в чем проблема. Дайте полный код (HTML+JS) и что вы конкретно хотите получить, и что получаете вместо этого.

Answer (score 3):

Есть глобальный и локальный scope ( область видимости ), глобальный виден везде, локальный только в своей области ( чаще всего ограничен функцией )

```
var num = 0; // глобальная переменная
function test (num) {
   /* здесь num, num1 - локальная переменная */
   var num1 = 10;
}
```

Любой параметр ф-ции - это локальная переменная, создается автоматически во время вызова, все переменные объявленные через `var` внутри ф-ции - тоже локальные. 
Проблема начинается тогда, когда мы **глобальную** переменную, через параметр передаем в ф-цию, тогда создается **локальная** переменная, куда записывается **значение глобальной**, и работа ведется с **локальной** переменной, а **не с глобальной**

Есть несколько способов изменить глобальную переменную внутри в ф-ции: 
1 - Использовать свойство ее глобальности и не передавать ее, как параметр

```
var num = 0;
function test () {
   num = 10 // без var! иначе получим локальную переменную
}
test();
alert(num) // 10
```

2 - возвращать результат функции в глобальную переменную

```
var num = 0;
function test (num) {
    num = 10;
    return num;
}
num = test();
alert(num) // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Во второй функции `ChangeValue` убери `num` из аргументов. В твоём случае `num` становится локальной переменной `ChangeValue` и после вызова функции не меняет глобальную `num`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Про развёрнутые ответы принято, хорошо. Про области видимости уже пояснили. Я рассматривал только те две функции, что в вопросе. Здесь глобальная переменная num передана ChangeValue формальным параметром, потому ChangeValue не изменяла глобальную num, как того хотел вопрощающий.